# How to activate the button in popup window in Electron Js?

Tags: javascript, button, electron, typeerror, ipc

I have an Electron JS project. There are 2 buttons, one of them in index.html (for the main page), and the other is in popup.html (for the popup window). There is no problem with buttons in index.html. However, I can not click the buttons in the popup window.

This is for creating popup window in main.js:

```
     // to open popup window
     ipcMain.on('open-popup', (event) => {
        popupWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 500, height: 400 });
        popupWindow.loadFile('renderer/popup.html');
               
      });
```

To open the popup window first click the button on the main page. After opening the popup window, listen to the button in the popup window.

This is renderer.js:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // mainbutton
    const mainButton = document.getElementById('main');
    mainButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        console.log("Clicked main button!!");
        ipcRenderer.send('open-popup');
    });
    const popupButton = document.getElementById('popup');
    popupButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
         console.log("Clicked popup button in popup window!!");
    });

});
```

When I run the code I  get this error for popup button:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

There is no problem with id names, they're correct. How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: I get the error in popupButton.addEventListener().

Comment: It is important to know what line the error occurs on, but given that you said that the other buttons worked, I suspect it's `popupButton.addEventListener` that's making trouble here. TL;DR: You cannot cross-access the DOM of a different window (neither can you when you're developing for browsers if you're trying to do it your way). Please read up on Electron's process model in the [official documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model).

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner So is there any way to do this? That is, apart from making popup windows, for example. Or how can I add this to the main HTML?